# Relativistic trajectory in a constant electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, classical-mechanics, relative-motion

I'm trying to write the trajectory ($y^i = y^i(t),\ i \in \{1, 2, 3\},\ y^0 = t$) of a particle seen from an inertial reference frame, ${\cal O\ '}$, that moves along $y^2$ axis with constant speed $(0, v, 0)$ respect to another inertial reference frame, ${\cal O}$, which is at rest and coincides in origins at $t = 0$.

In ${\cal O}$ there is constant electric field $\vec{E} = (E, 0, 0)$, but due to special relativity in ${\cal O\ '}$ you'll see a magnetic field also.

Solving the differential equations in ${\cal O\ '}$ and using the initial conditions $y^\mu(t = 0) = 0,\ \frac{dy^i}{ds}(t = 0) = 0,\ \frac{dy^0}{ds}(t = 0) = 1$; I get, with proper time $s$, the following worldline:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
y^0\\
y^1\\
y^2\\
y^3
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
(\gamma^2/a)\sinh(as) - \gamma^2v^2s\\
(\gamma/a)(\cosh(as) - 1)\\
v\gamma^2s - (v\gamma^2/a)\sinh(as)\\
0
\end{pmatrix},\qquad \gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - v^2}}, \qquad a = \frac{eE}{m}
$$

$m$ is the mass of the particle and $e$ its electric charge.

But if I want to write $y^i(t)$ instead of $y^i(s)$ with $t = y^0$, you have a big problem: $y^0(s)$ is a transcendental function mixing lineal and hiperbolic $s$-dependence. So, is there any way to get explicit relation among $y^i$ and $y^0$ or we can just restric ourselves to a computer? The computer will give you a table relating those values via fixing $s$, so you obtain the corresponding $(y^0, y^i)$ pair for each $s$

Comment: What is $a$? And $s$?

Comment: @SuperCiocia Non-relativistic classical acceleration and proper time as the post says

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe that there is a simple expression?

Comment: It’s weird having $\gamma$ in your solution, since it would be a function of $s$.

Comment: @G.Smith It is not weird since that $\gamma$ is depending only in the initial speed of ${\cal O\ '}$, $v$, which is constant

Comment: Moreover, it is perfectly reasonable for $1/\sqrt{1-v^2}$ to be in the equations of ${\cal O\ '}$ since the electric field you'll see there is $\gamma E$ while in ${\cal O}$ is just $E$. Therefore, the electric force will be corrected by that $\gamma$

Comment: Sorry, I see now that $v$ is the relative velocity between the frames. Do you have some reason to think that $y^i(t)$ is supposed to be a simple expression?

Comment: @G.Smith Not really